# Deduce the correct specialized member method of a class to match the data type of variable it is assigned to

Tags: c++

I have a class that reads a script and stores variables and their respective types which I reference by name (string). The class has a templatized member method named `get`, which fetches the variable that matches the `name` parameter from one of the member tables, and needs to return data of the same type as the variable type it is assigned to. To better illustrate my question, suppose I have a simplified class such as:

```
class Script
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    T get(std::string name);

private:
    //data stored in associative containers such as:
    // std::map<std::string, int> int_data;
    // std::map<std::string, bool> bool_data;
};
```

In the implementation file, the member method is specialized:

```
template <>
int Script::get(std::string name)
{
    int value = retrieve_integer(name);
    return value;
}

template <>
bool Script::get(std::string name)
{
    bool value = retrieve_boolean(name);
    return value;
}
```

I would like to call the class method like this without explicitly providing the type with `script.get<int>("varName")`:

```
Script script; // loads script and reads data
bool useVsync = script.get("useVsync"); // calls the bool specific get
int screenWidth = script.get("screenWidth"); // calls the int specific get
```

How would I do this without causing *could not deduce template parameter T* errors? I know that this should be possible, because I have used libraries that allowed such syntax.

Comment: This isn't possible, you misunderstood what the libraries are doing. The *exact* snippet you provided *is* possible, but probably not in the way you think.

Comment: Why do you not want to provide the type in the call? Does the calling code not know the type of the value it will obtain?

Comment: @PasserBy It is possible. Just return a `ValueProxy` from `get()`, and the `ValueProxy` has a templated conversion operator.

Comment: @liliscent That fails in multitudes of ways including in type deduction. It is also not what OP showed in the second snippet.

Comment: Sorry, but C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @PasserBy Why? That can *literally* achieve `bool useVsync = script.get("useVsync"); ` API

Comment: @liliscent But not when `std::cout << script.get("useVsync")`.

Comment: @liliscent it's seems like you have a workable idea. Can you clarify what you mean by a proxy value?

Comment: @PasserBy I only intend to use the the `get` method to assign to variables, where the correct method template matches that variable's type.

Comment: @SA Read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator and my first comment.

Comment: @liliscent I did as you suggested, I made a proxy class template with a member variable `T value` and method `operator T()` which returns `value`, and the `Script::get()` now returns `ValueProxy<T>`. I get the same template deduction error. Apparently what I want is an advanced language feature that probably doesn't work the way I think it does as @PasserBy suggested. But I think you pointed me in the right direction with a proxy value and type cast operators.

Comment: @SA  *I did as you suggested* --> That's not what I said. `ValueProxy` is not a template. https://wandbox.org/permlink/sWK1uHOospL1gNsx

Comment: @liliscent Thanks for providing the example code. I added what you did in my project and it compiles and works perfectly, exactly the way I wanted it to! Now, on a side note, if I wanted to create a similar method called `set(std::string name, T value)` I assume I'd use the same approach and create an overloaded `operator =` within the `ValueProxy` struct? I appreciate your helpful replies.

Comment: @liliscent what I meant to write was, if I went further to replace `get` and `set` with the `operator [] (std::string name)`, I would have to create an overloaded `operator =` within the `ValueProxy` struct to allow assigning values likewise: `script["varName"] = 900`? I appreciate your helpful replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comment, you may abuse of conversion operator:

```
class Script
{
public:
    struct ValueProxy {
        operator bool() const {
            return script.bool_data[name];
        }
        operator int() const {
            return script.int_data[name];
        }

        ValueProxy& operator= (bool b) {script.bool_data[name] = b;}
        ValueProxy& operator= (int n)  {script.int_data[name] = n;}

        Script &script;
        std::string name;
    };

    ValueProxy get(std::string name) {
        return ValueProxy{*this, std::move(name)};
    }

private:
    //data stored in associative containers such as:
    std::map<std::string, int> int_data;
    std::map<std::string, bool> bool_data;
};

int main() {
    Script script;

    script.get("myBool") = true;
    script.get("MyInt") = 42;

    bool b = script.get("MyBool"); // true
    int i = script.get("MyInt"); // 42
    int j = script.get("MyBool"); // 0
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. I also added `ValueProxy operator [](std::string name)` within `Script` class which returns `return ValueProxy{*this, std::move(name)};` which allows me to get and set values via `bool b = script["MyBool"]` and `script["MyInt"] = 42`. This ValueProxy is an awesome technique. Thanks for further extending @liliscent's example.